# How to don't allow set only the same characters and only special sign - regex js

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for some regex pattern to:

- not allow set the same characters
- not allow only special signs.

So:

- 11111111 - not allow
- 1111811111 - allow
- rrrrrrrr - not allow
- rrrrrrrrrr5 - allow
- 11111111% - allow
- %$!@$!@@@@ - not allow
- %%%%%%%%%1 - allow

I found regex which is helpful for recognize that string has only special sign: /^\W*\w.*$/, but I don't know how to join it with condition about not only repeated characters. Thansks for any advices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can assert not only the same characters and make sure to match at least a single word character.

```
^(?!(.)\1+$)[^\w\n]*\w.*$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!(.)\1+$)` Negative lookahead, assert not only the same characters in the string matching at least 2 characters
- `[^\w\n]*` Optionally match any character except a word character or newline
- `\w` Match at least a single word character
- `.*` Optionally match any character
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EKdObG/1)

```js
const regex = /^(?!(.)\1+$)[^\w\n]*\w.*$/;
[
  "11111111",
  "1111811111",
  "rrrrrrrr",
  "rrrrrrrrrr5",
  "11111111%",
  "%$!@$!@@@@",
  "%%%%%%%%%1",
  "a"
].forEach(s => {
  if (regex.test(s)) {
    console.log(s + " allow")
  } else {
    console.log(s + " not allow")
  }
});
```

---

If you don't want to match any spaces in the string, you can match non whitespace chars using `\S`

```
^(?!(\S)\1+$)[^\w\s]*\w\S*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bBD161/1)

Comment: Great answer, thanks! I have one more detail: how can change it for allow also only one characters? Because for min length I have another validation, and here I need only check repeat motive. So string 'a' also have to be allowed.

Comment: @emka26 Like this? `^(?!(.)\1+$)[^\w\n]*\w.*$` https://regex101.com/r/TMxydS/1